# Deactivating Custom ARIA Label in Clarity Design Table (AngularJS)

Tags: angular, clarity

In my AngularJS project, I've incorporated Clarity Design for styling. Within a table, Clarity Design has introduced a custom ARIA label that I'd like to deactivate. However, I've been unable to locate the source of this ARIA label within my components.

I've tried inspecting the table element, reviewing the Clarity Design documentation, and checking my component files, but I can't pinpoint where this ARIA label is being set.

Could someone provide guidance on how I might deactivate or customize this specific ARIA label in a Clarity Design table within my AngularJS project?

Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBWqF.png)

```
 <section class="pb-4">
                        <clr-datagrid *ngIf="bericht.taetigkeiten.length > 0; else keineDaten" 
                                      [(clrDgSingleSelected)]="selectedIdTaetigkeit" [attr.aria-label]="null" >
                                      
                          <clr-dg-action-bar>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="{{idPrefix}}_button_freisetzungsberechnung"
                                      (click)="navigateToFreisetzungsberechnung(selectedIdTaetigkeit)"
                                       [attr.aria-disabled]="!taetigkeitenActive || !selectedIdTaetigkeit"
                                      *ngIf="isCompVisible('prtr-bericht.btnFreisetzungsBerechnung')">
                                <cds-icon shape="calculator" class="disabledCase" aria-hidden="true"></cds-icon>
```